# Reload web page on mysql table update using ajax call

Tags: javascript

that is my ajax call:

```
function getEle(id) {
    var element = new Array();

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "map.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "id": id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var resultArr = new Array();
            var resultArr = data;
            var state = new Array();

            for (var s = 0; s < resultArr.length; s++) {
                state[s] = resultArr[s];
                element[s] = id;
                element[s] = state[s];
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
    return element;
}
```

Have some solution kindly post it..... thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.location` in javascript.

```
success: function (data) {
            var resultArr = new Array();
            var resultArr = data;
            var state = new Array();

            for (var s = 0; s < resultArr.length; s++) {
                state[s] = resultArr[s];
                element[s] = id;
                element[s] = state[s];
            }

          window.location = "yourpage address";// add this line 

        }
```